# animating position change without defining keyframe

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

i have a simple menu / submenue

```
<ul>
 <li class="parent">

   parent

   <div class="child">
       some stuff
   </div>

 </li>
</ul>
```

here is css

```
.parent { position : relative ; display:inline-block; background:green ; width:500px ; height : 50px  }
.child { 

position: absolute ; display:none ; background:red ;width:100% ; bottom:-100px ; height : 50px;opacity:0 ;

            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}
.parent:hover .child { display:block ; bottom:-50px ; opacity : 1  }
```

here is jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/7o3fxqvr/1/

basically i want child to appear when the mouse is hovered on parent ... also

bottom changes from -100px to -50px to show the child move a little toward parent , this change of bottom should be shown as animation but it just jumps above and appears there's  no  animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to doing that is to give a large negative value for the `left` property when it's completely hidden and use a transition-delay so that the other properties have time to transition. The downside is that all properties to be transitioned on the element have to be specified individually.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: -999em;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  /* the -o- and -ms- prefixes are not needed for this property */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, margin 1s ease-in-out, left 0s 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, margin 1s ease-in-out,left 0s 1s;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, margin 1s ease-in-out,left 0s 1s;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, margin 1s ease-in-out,left 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, margin 1s ease-in-out,left 0s;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, margin 1s ease-in-out,left 0s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">

    parent

    <div class="child">
      some stuff
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove display block and none which you have used to hide and show. Since you are using opacity to hide you can do the animation with opacity.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -100px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  bottom: -50px;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">

    parent

    <div class="child">
      some stuff
    </div>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi , the problem with that is when i move my mouse under the `parent` where the child is , its going to show the child ... becuz technically parent:hover is happening

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.main{
   position: relative;
  width:500px;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width:100%;
  bottom: -100px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.parent:hover + .child {
  bottom: -50px;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="main">
  <li class="parent">
    parent
  </li>
        <div class="child">
      some stuff
    </div>
</ul>
```

just wrapped both in one div! and make both child and parent classes as sibling !

Comment: that way when you hover on the child it would disappear , i've put the child inside parent so it when you are hovering over child you would also hovering the parent ... that way child would still be visible